# How to add different hyperlinks to data-*?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML code:

```
<article class="article" data-quota="Here goes nothing" data-share="Here goes social" data-tag1="Tag1" data-tag2="Tag2" data-tag3="Tag3">
  <h3>Author name</h3>
</article>
```

and the JS:

```
function articleTemplate() {
  $('.article').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        dataQuota = $this.data('quota'),
        dataTag1 = $this.data('tag1'),
        dataTag2 = $this.data('tag2'),
        dataTag3 = $this.data('tag3'),
        dataShare = $this.data('share');

    var template =  '<h4>' + dataQuota + '</h4>' +
                    '<h5>' + dataTag1 + ',' + dataTag2 + ',' + dataTag3 + '</h5>' +
                    '<footer>' + dataShare + '</footer>';

    $this.append(template);
  });
}
```

I am doing some templateing with javascript and until now I got this. 
The outputed html is:

```
<h3>Author name</h3>
<h4>Here goes nothing</h4>
<h5>Tag1,Tag2,Tag3</h5>
<footer>Here goes social</footer>
```

Now I want to add hyperlinks to data-quota, data-share, data-tag1, etc.?

Comment: If the posted line of code is your *input*, what do you expect to end up with as your *output*? What JavaScript did you try, where did you get stuck? What went wrong? What errors did you get? What didn't work as it should? What did you *expect* to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: I dont have any errors. But now I want to add hyperlink to every outputed text. Hope my english is clear enough.

Comment: But where would the `<a>` elements go? Given the posted HTML what should the resulting DOM look like? I'm happy to help but if I just start making guesses then it's unlikely to be helpful.

Comment: added the html output. hope it helps

Comment: But there are no `<a>` elements in your posted output; what text do you want to link to what destination site?

Comment: I want the h3 outputed text to have a link (ex: diversifiacation1.html), h4 outputed text to have a link (ex: diversifiacation2.html) and so on. I can add easy the <a> tag where is needed.

Comment: it's ok... i've succeded. many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You how different options. One would be to write it that way:

```
<article class="article" data-quota-content="Here goes nothing" data-quota-href="/some/link">
  <h3>Author name</h3>
</article>
```

jQuery will automatically convert the data into a nested object.

And equivalent solution would be to put a JSON formatted string into your attribute this will also be automatically parsed:

```
<article class="article" data-quota='{"content":"Here goes nothing", "href":"/some/link"}'>
  <h3>Author name</h3>
</article>
```

So if you write:

```
 var $this = $(this),
     dataQuota = $this.data('quota')
```

Then `dataQuota` will be an object containing:

```
{
   content : "Here goes nothing",
   href : "/some/link"
}
```

And you could use it that way:

```
var template =  '<h4><a href="'+dataQuota.href+'">' + dataQuota.content + '</a></h4>' +
```

As a note, you should not create html code like you did above, a better way is to create it that way:

```
$this.append( 
   $('<h4>').append(
       $('<a>')
          .attr('href',dataQuota.href)
          .text(dataQuota.content)
   )
);
```

This ensures that you don't have get problems with escaping.

Comment: many thanks for the answer, but I have found another way.. thanks a lot

Comment: @Bobita if you found another way then you should share this as an answer.

Comment: thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Just some simple tweek to js file:

```
function articleTemplate() {
    $('.article').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            dataQuota = $this.data('quota'),
            dataTag1 = $this.data('tag1'),
            dataTag2 = $this.data('tag2'),
            dataTag3 = $this.data('tag3'),
            dataShare = $this.data('share');

        var template =  '<h4><a href="' + url + '">' + dataQuota + '</a></h4>' +
                        '<h5><a href="' + url2 + '">' + dataTag1 + '</a>,' + dataTag2 + ',' + dataTag3 + '</h5>' +
                        '<footer>' + dataShare + '</footer>';

        $this.append(template);
    });

}

var url = "http://bencollier.net/";
var url2 = "http://google.ro/";
```

Comment: But then you question was not right, you asked  `How to add different hyperlinks to data-*`. But you have two fixed urls that you add to `h4` and `h5` and they are the same for every `article`.

Comment: @t.niese I didn't manage to do it with my script... can you post your script again please